# Decimal including negative to 32 bit binary converter

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, negative-number

I tried to convert decimal numbers (including negatives) to binary numbers but sadly I cant make it work it seems.

```
int main()
{
    QString input = "00000000000000000000000000000101";  //positive 5
    int dec = input.ToInt(); 


    char bin32[]  = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    for (int pos = 31; pos >= 0 && dec; --pos)
    {
        if (dec % 2) 
            bin32[pos] = '1';
        dec /= 2;
    }

    cout << "The binary of the given number is: " << bin32 << endl;
}
```

When I give -5 as `input`, `dec` is also -5 but binary number is not. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your loop assumes `dec` is non-negative.   Logically, it needs to be modified to handle a negative value.

Comment: Probably not the point of the exercise, but `input.toInt(nullptr, 2)` and `QString::number(n, 2)` can convert from/to binary strings

Comment: Your example input is 101, not positive 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that `-1 % 2 == -1` and `if (-1)` is true. So your algorithm produces the exact same result for `x` and `-x`.

One way of fixing it is to use an `unsigned int` in your loop:

```
unsigned int num = dec;

char bin32[] = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
for (int pos = 31; pos >= 0; --pos)
{
    if (num % 2)
        bin32[pos] = '1';
    num /= 2;
}
```

Another is to use bit-wise operators instead of arithmetic:

```
int dec = -5;

char bin32[] = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
for (int pos = 0; pos < 32; ++pos)
{
    if (dec & (1 << pos))
        bin32[31-pos] = '1';
}
```

Comment: I want to see negatives bits too so for example -5 would be 1111111111111011

Comment: Both code samples I posted produce `1111111111111011` when `dec = -5`